# Bug occurs only when compiling with -O3

Tags: gcc, cython, glfw

While making an OpenGL toolkit using GLFW and Cython I stumbled upon a very, very weird issue. I created the following file pxd file (quite large, so I gisted it):

https://gist.github.com/1441970

Next I have this wrapping code (extremely simplified to show the core of the problem).

#### pygrafix.window module:

```
from pygrafix.c_headers.glfw cimport * # this is the pxd file

glfwInit()

_window = None

cdef void _mouse_scroll_callback_handler(int pos):
    if _window._mouse_scroll_callback:
        _window._mouse_scroll_callback(_window, pos)

cdef class Window:
    cdef public object _mouse_scroll_callback

    def __cinit__(self):
        global _window
        self._mouse_scroll_callback = None

        _window = self

    def __init__(self, int width = 0, int height = 0):
        glfwOpenWindow(width, height, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, GLFW_WINDOW)
        glfwSetMouseWheelCallback(<GLFWmousewheelfun> &_mouse_scroll_callback_handler)
        print("TEST LOCATION ONE")

    def is_open(self):
        return glfwGetWindowParam(GLFW_OPENED)

    def flip(self):
        glfwSwapBuffers()

    def set_mouse_scroll_callback(self, func):
        self._mouse_scroll_callback = func
```

And this main file:

```
from pygrafix import window

window = window.Window(800, 600)
print("TEST LOCATION TWO")

def on_scroll(window, pos):
    print(pos)

window.set_mouse_scroll_callback(on_scroll)

while window.is_open():
    window.flip()
```

And finally I compile it like this:

```
cython.py -o pygrafix/window.cy.c pygrafix/window.pyx
gcc -O3 -shared -DGLFW_DLL -IC:\Python27\include pygrafix/window.cy.c -o pygrafix/window.pyd -LC:\Python27\libs -lpython27 -lgfwldll
```

But it crashes (windows says there was an error in the program). When I comment out the call to `glfwSetMouseWheelCallback` it doesn't crash.
The strange thing is, if I compile with -O0 **it doesn't crash and works as it should!** I am completely baffled by this. I checked the C code that cython outputs, and it looks ok.
`_mouse_scroll_callback_handler` is of the type `void (*)(int)`, and the pointer to it gets passed nicely into glfw.

Other oddities:

- This only happens with `glfwSetMouseWheelCallback` (or at least to me), not with glwSetMousePosCallback for example.
- If I pass NULL to `glfwSetMouseWheelCallback`, there is no problem.
- Even if there is a crash, TEST LOCATION ONE still gets printed, but TEST LOCATION TWO doesn't.
- It also works if I compile with -O3 -pg

What could possibly be the cause of this, and what would be the correct fix (without having to compile at -O0)?

---

Other trivia:

I'm using Windows 7 64 bit, GLFW 2.7.2, Cython 0.15.1, GCC 4.6.1 under MinGW and CPython 2.7.2.

Comment: it is most likely an optimization bug (of the compiler)

Comment: Can you post the backtrace ? I would suggest you to test your lib other a memory analyser. This might be due to an uninitialized memory, and lead to this kind of weird bug.

Comment: Why do you need a cast to `GLFWmousewheelfun`? That's suspicious. If the function that you use as the callback doesn't have the correct type that would explain crashes.

Comment: @sth: I have no idea. The warning that I get otherwise is (along the lines of): `Warning: expected GLFWmousewheelfun, got void (*)(int)`. And `GLFWmousewheelfun` is defined as `typedef void(GLFWCALL*  GLFWmousewheelfun)(int)` with `GLFWCALL` being `__stdcall` or something like that.

Comment: Again, if you didn't test with memory analyser (i don't know anyone on windows, but i'm thinking about something like valgrind), you might seen what you're doing it wrong. For example, if you are overwriting 3 bytes somewhere outside allocated memory, you might erase some important information. Maybe -O3, -pg, -O0 trigger a different memory organization, and you don't see the bug / seeing it with the crash. A deeper analysis is required here :)

Comment: @tito: Thanks, I will try my best to get more information, I would have probably solved this long ago if it were not that I have no internet at home. I will try running valgrind of my program.

Comment: @sth: As it turns out you were right, see my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution. The problem was that I didn't add `__stdcall` in Cython to the callback functions, nor did I know it supported this.